# How to execute part of the code on Quarkus when starting the application?

Tags: java, quarkus

Please help me understand that how to execute part of the code on Quarkus when starting the application?
If possible, discard the link or give an example code.
Thanks.

Comment: could you be more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an @Startup annotation for Quarkus that will instantiate a service upon startup. It simply automates the listening of the StartupEvent:

*For each bean annotated with @Startup a synthetic observer of StartupEvent is generated. The default priority is used.*

Works well.

[Quarkus @Startup annotation](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#startup_annotation)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure to understand your question but if you want to execute code at startup, the easiest way is to observe (using `@Observes`) the `StartupEvent` with a CDI bean:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppLifecycleBean {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("ListenerBean");

    void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {               
        LOGGER.info("The application is starting...");
    }

    void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) {               
        LOGGER.info("The application is stopping...");
    }

}
```

You can find more details in our documentation if you need a better understanding of the Quarkus application lifecycle:
https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#listening-for-startup-and-shutdown-events

Comment: Thank you for answer

Comment: @guillaume-smet is there any after startup event? I'm calling another API to get some info, I would like to do it after startup not increasing startup time.